# Oracle - Update string to replace only the last character

Tags: replace, sql-update, oracle9i, substr

I have the following string in an Oracle 9i database:

A,B,C,

I need to replace all instances of ',' when it is the last item in the string. I have come up with the following statement but it deletes everything in the field not just the comma. Any suggestions?

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(SUBSTR(column, -1, 1), ',', '');
```

Comment: Thank you! The comment `UPDATE  mytable
SET     column = SUBSTR(column, 1, LENGTH(column) - 1)
WHERE   SUBSTR(column, -1, 1) = ','` worked for me. The others still blanked out the whole line instead of just the last ','.

Comment: You're getting null cause the function `REPLACE` returns null - check my updated answer

Comment: Excellent thanks! Would a similar function work if I was trying to remove a ',' that was the first character of a string? (,A,B,C)

Comment: @RahulTripathi the "thank you" wasn't for you - I caught the "where" issue and Quassnoi caught the "replace" thing (and you changed your answer after you saw it!). Please don't take credit that doesn't belong to you!

Comment: that would actually be even "easier" cause you can do: `UPDATE table SET column = SUBSTR(column, 2) 
WHERE SUBSTR(column, 1, 1) = ',';`

Comment: They both work perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add the condition: `WHERE SUBSTR(column, -1, 1) = ','`
Quassnoi caught another issue - REPLACE returns null - you can't use it inside the "set"

Full sql:

```
UPDATE table SET column = SUBSTR(column, 0, length(column)-1) 
WHERE SUBSTR(column, -1, 1) = ',';
```

This will make sure you're doing the substitute only in rows that has values that ends with ","

Comment: Or possibly `WHERE column LIKE '%,'`

Answer (score 9):

`rtrim(column, ',')` is both efficient and much shorter

Comment: I think this answer look more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka, are you bothered more with answer's brevity or utility? Both are superior, imho. )

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     column = SUBSTR(column, 1, LENGTH(column) - 1)
WHERE   SUBSTR(column, -1, 1) = ','
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer 'column' only 1 time in your query, just do as following:

`UPDATE table SET column = REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(column), 2));`

Answer (score 0):

To change a single instance of a character in a specific position in a string, let's say a code like this 'IM0B010011'.
I would use this code:

```sql
select substr('IM0B010011',1,length('IM0B010011')-1) || (substr('IM0B010011',-1)+1)
from dual;
```

Result:
'IM0B010012'